# ```Bull queue error: ReplyError: MOVED 4913 dev-.use2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379``` while connecting with adding and processing BULL queue```

Tags: redis, bull, bullmq

I tried to run  BULL queue with aws redis cluster. But i am facing this error `Bull queue error: ReplyError: MOVED 4913 dev-.use2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379` while connecting with adding and processing BULL queue```

I have tried adding hash before prefix name and queue name.My attempt looks like this

```
const testLayerQueue = new Queue('{my-queue}', {
   redis: {
     host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
     port: 6379,
     password: process.env.REDIS_PWD, 
     tls: {
         servername: process.env.REDIS_HOST
       },
   },
   prefix: '{myapp}'  
 },{ settings: { lockDuration: lockDurationTime } });
```